# Node: SerialPort is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, linux, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to connect to my Raspberry pi's serialport via node but when i run the js file it comes up with this error:

```js
    var serialport = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyAMA0", {
                 ^

TypeError: SerialPort is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pi/exploringrpi/chp13/xbee/nodejs/test.js:12:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
```

node is at version 8.11.4
serialport is at version 7.0.2

This is the code:

```js
// From the example code at www.npmjs.com/package/xbee-api
var util       = require('util');
var SerialPort = require('serialport').SerialPort;

var xbee_api   = require('xbee-api');
var C          = xbee_api.constants;

var xbeeAPI = new xbee_api.XBeeAPI({
  api_mode: 1
});

var serialport = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyAMA0", {
        baudRate: 115200});
serialport.on("open", function() {
  var frame_obj = {                 // AT Request to be sent to
    type: C.FRAME_TYPE.AT_COMMAND,  // Prepare for an AT command
    command: "NI",                  // Node identifer command
    commandParameter: [],           // No parameters needed
  };
  serialport.write(xbeeAPI.buildFrame(frame_obj));
});

// The data frames are outputted by this function
xbeeAPI.on("frame_object", function(frame) {
    console.log(">>", frame);
});
```

Hope you can help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably remove the `.SerialPort` at the end of the require line:

```
var SerialPort = require('serialport').SerialPort;
```

The [serial port documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serialport) shows how it should be used, and it doesn't include that `.SerialPort` at the end:

```
var SerialPort = require('serialport');
var port = new SerialPort('/dev/ttyAMA0', {
  baudRate: /dev/ttyAMA0
});
```

Comment: as from 10x it is `var port = new SerialPort({ path: '/dev/ttyUSB0', baudRate: 9600 });`, more details see [Upgrade Guide | Node SerialPort](https://serialport.io/docs/guide-upgrade#upgrading-from-9x-to-10x)

Answer (score 0):

Another error was shown to me:
throw new TypeError(`"path" is not defined: ${settings.path}`);

I created the port object like this:
const sp = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyACM0", {baudRate: 4800});
It was wrong way.
Try to create port and define the path inside curl brackets:
const sp = new SerialPort({path: "/dev/ttyACM0", baudRate: 4800});

```
const SerialPort = require('serialport').SerialPort;
const sp = new SerialPort({path: "/dev/ttyACM0", baudRate: 4800});

const sent_data = '\x45';

sp.on("open", function() {
    console.log("port has opened");

    sp.write(sent_data, function(err){
        if(err){
            return console.log('Error on write', err.message);
        }
        console.log('Port.write: ', sent_data);
    });
});

sp.on('data', function(data){
    // decoding uint8Array to string
    var enc = new TextDecoder();
    var arr = new Uint8Array(data);
    ready = enc.decode(arr)

    console.log('Data received: ', ready);
});

// Read data that is available but keep the stream from entering "flowing mode"
sp.on('readable', function () {
    console.log('Data2:', sp.read());
});
```